# Create 5 second intro from image and concatenate to a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make a 5 second intro from `55.png`, and concatenate it to the beginning of `55.mp4`. I would like to incorporate it into this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 55.mp4 -i intro -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=1.15,volume=1.6,pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1) [amain]; [0:v]setpts=PTS/1.15,crop=iw/1.2:ih/1.2,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [vmain]; [1:v]scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [vintro]; [vintro][1:a][vmain][amain]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 1400k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -bufsize 500000k -threads 0 -preset superfast out2222.mp4
```

Info about my ffmpeg and about `55.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-04-13-59e3a9a Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg develop
ers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libb
luray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --e
nable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-lib
twolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --
enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --e
nable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo
-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom
--disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --ena
ble-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable
-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 78.102 / 58. 78.102
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '55.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2020-03-26T08:17:13.000000Z
  Duration: 00:04:29.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1402 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709)
, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1270 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 t
bc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-26T08:17:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 03/26
/2020.
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-26T08:17:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 03/26
/2020.
```

Info about `55.png`:

```
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 305x432 [SAR 3778:3778 DAR 305:432], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

Comment: post updated, added the code shown from video

Comment: boss sorry, allow me to provide the info for the intro.mp4 made from ffmpeg, this is the one that prevents the compile to work

Comment: Post updated sir sorry for the confusion, what am trying to do is create a intro.mp4 using the command line rather than opening sony vegas, everytime and then compile the intro with my 55.mp4, i just want to make intro.mp4 using command line and compile it with the final code i have

Comment: Just use the image itself as an input, loop it, and concat it  yes please this is exactly what i want to do, i just want a 5 second intro using my 55.png then start my original video wich is 55.mp4  ffmpeg -i 55.png wait i wil post it

Comment: post updated. added 55.png info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -y -i 55.mp4 -loop 1 -framerate 30000/1001 -t 5 -i 55.png -t 0.5 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=1.15,volume=1.6,pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1) [amain]; [0:v]setpts=PTS/1.15,crop=iw/1.2:ih/1.2,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [vmain]; [1:v]premultiply=inplace=1,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[vintro]; [vintro][2][vmain][amain]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -b:v 1400k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -bufsize 500000k -threads 0 -preset superfast out2222.mp4
```

- The intro needs audio to concat to the audio of `55.mp4` or else concat will fail. This example uses the [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filter to generate silent audio. A short duration is declared because anullsrc duration by default is infinite. The [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter will automatically extend this shortened duration to match its associated video segment.
- The width, height, and aspect ratio of the `55.png` is modified with the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad), and [setsar](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setsar) filters to match those of `55.mp4`.

Comment: 1 word excellent Bravo, 1 issue is the intro logo is to big,it enlarges to much can we have it fit center?

Comment: Can we have it centered like this https://i.imgur.com/DEsi9Fr.png  ,And look at your updated code image https://i.imgur.com/gFk7S2R.png

Comment: intro should be like this https://streamable.com/0sj61i

Comment: new update 100% correct, can you remove white background if not its ok since the image is png transperant it should be plain right ? if you cant its ok let me know thank you and yes you read my mind it is exactly how i want it.

Comment: @das Provide a link to `55.png`.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/v2fzSUS.png i also notice the video playback is 1x extra fast? can i tune it to be normal

Comment: https://streamable.com/rx4ye8 your video time 2:37
https://streamable.com/r1tv48 original video  go to time 2:56 and listen to sound playback compare

Comment: @das That's due to your inclusion of `atempo=1.15` and `setpts=PTS/1.15` which I assumed you wanted to keep.

Comment: thanks sir, am compiling and tuning that line of code and testing which is better for me,sorry about that,can you remove the white background

Comment: @das See updated answer. Most PNG with alpha wouldn't need premultiply filter, but yours does.

Comment: the audo how do to make it sound better just like original video no hissing noise higher audio quality

Comment: @das Remove `volume=1.6` as the audio volume is probably clipping. This is becoming a never ending series of questions. I already answered the main question. The rest of these questions are not related to the main question of "how to add intro". You're supposed to make one question and it gets one answer. Then if you have another, separate issue you post a new question and it gets its own answer.

Comment: thank you @llogan you was so helpful may god bless you

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -y -i 55.mp4 -loop 1 -framerate 30000/1001 -t 5 -i 55.png -t 0.5 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=1.15,volume=1.6,pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1) [amain]; [0:v]setpts=PTS/1.15,crop=iw/1.2:ih/1.2,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [vmain]; [1:v]premultiply=inplace=1,scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[vintro]; [vintro][2][vmain][amain]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -b:v 1400k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -bufsize 500000k -threads 0 -preset superfast out2222.mp4
```